# Save contact form 7 data in user profile (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, contact-form-7

I am trying to safe the information from a 'contactform 7' into my user profiles.
I found the same question here from a few years ago and tried the same code but without any success.

[This is the link to the question where I got this code from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137624/contact-form-7-to-wordpress-user-database)

And below is the code I used on my website

```php
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'cf7import',1);
function cf7import() {
    $title = $contact_form->title;
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $submission ) 
    {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data(); 
        $formtitle = $cfdata->title; } 
        if ( $formtitle == 'Form title') { 
    }
     global $wpdb; 
     $user_id = get_current_user_id();
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'email', $posted_data['Email'] );
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_login', $posted_data['Gebruikersnaam'] );
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $posted_data['billing-first-name'] );
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', $posted_data['billing-last-name'] );
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $posted_data['billing-first-name'] );
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name', $posted_data['billing-last-name'] );
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_company', $posted_data['billing-company'] );
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', $posted_data['billing-address-1'] );
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', $posted_data['billing-city'] );
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', $posted_data['billing-postcode'] );

 }
```

I asked the question before but it was marked as offtopic. Probably because my code was too long or unclear what I was talking about. I hope it is good like this?

Comment: What have you done to try and debug this so far? Have you verified the function gets called at all? Have you stepped through it in a debugger, or made debug outputs at least to verify how far it goes, and what these `update_user_meta` calls returned, if it gets this far?

Comment: You might want to edit your title to "Save" instead of "Safe" so that it will be more help to other people.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your code.  Try this.

```php
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'cf7import', 1 );
// This function allows the $contact_form object to be passed
function cf7import($contact_form) {
    $title = $contact_form->title;
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $submission ) {
        // get posted data as array
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data(); 
        if ( $title == 'Form title') { 
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'email', $posted_data['Email'] );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_login', $posted_data['Gebruikersnaam'] );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $posted_data['billing-first-name'] );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', $posted_data['billing-last-name'] );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $posted_data['billing-first-name'] );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name', $posted_data['billing-last-name'] );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_company', $posted_data['billing-company'] );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', $posted_data['billing-address-1'] );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', $posted_data['billing-city'] );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', $posted_data['billing-postcode'] );
        }
    }
}
```